# Executing an executable after a bat file, from within my batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm building a dos batch file (or command batch file rather), which looks like this:

```
@echo off

set REGKEY=HKLM\Software\Adonix\X3RUNTIME\x3v6
set REGVAL=ADXDIR

REM query the value. pipe it through findstr in order to find the matching line that has the value. only grab token 3 and the remainder of the line. %%b is what we are interested in here.

set VALUE=
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('reg query %REGKEY% /v %REGVAL% ^| findstr %REGVAL%') do (
set myDir=%%b
)

%myDir%\bin\env.bat

Adonix.exe -v
pause
```

For some reason, this script stops executing after the `%myDir%\bin\env.bat` line; I'm not sure why.

I want it to run the `adonix -v` line, but it doesn't. In fact, if you put an `echo` just after the `env.bat` file, it still won't run.

Is there a way to run the `env.bat` file (which simply runs a bunch of `SET` commands for paths), have it perform those set commands, then run the `adonix.exe` next? Why does it stop running after `env.bat`?

Comment: Solution is to use
call %myDir%\bin\env.bat

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `call` to run another batch file from a batch file and want control passed back to you.